# Creating a internal private network using Public Corda v4.0

Tags: blockchain, corda

Can i use Official Corda Docker Image to create a private internal corda network using the Non enterprise corda v4.0 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whilst the answer about the enterprise network manager is correct if you wish to purchase the Corda Enterprise Network Manager.

The guys over at cordite have built an excellent network-map/doorman which can be used in private networks: https://gitlab.com/cordite/network-map-service they are also in #cordite on cordaledger slack.

IF you just want to get up and running quickly, there is a pre-built docker image that runs a doorman / networkmap using the development keystore available at: https://github.com/roastario/spring-boot-network-map

Answer (score 2):

You can indeed! But there are some nuances here. A Corda Network is really an instance of the following:

- A network map - an IP-address book for nodes to lookup other nodes
- A permissioning service - issues certificates to allow entities onto the network
- A Notary - signs transactions to prevent double-spends

We are working on productizing these services so that you can spin up your own private Corda Network (potentially in your LAN as you mentioned).

Right now however, these tools have only been internally deployed in infrastructure provisioned by the Corda Foundation (an independent legal entity we set up to manage Corda Networks). The networks that are available now are UAT (user acceptance testing) and the Corda Network.

You are free to join these networks and create your own business network. Which accomplishes the same thing using permissions at the software level. To do so you need to use BNMS - https://github.com/corda/corda-solutions/tree/master/bn-apps/memberships-management and join one of the existing networks that the Corda Foundation Manages (UAT / TestNet). Another helpful link is https://manosbatsis.github.io/corbeans/docs/starter-bnms.html which standardizes a web server for getting a node into BNMS.

I will update this post when Corda Enterprise Network Manager is released (within the next few months)! (This is the name of the product that will include the notary, permissioning service and network map). Cheers!

Comment: This answer isn't focussing on the question which is about a *private* network. Not joining existing networks.